# C: how to convert this code for an use with array?

Tags: arrays, c, loops, if-statement, function-definition

Consider I'm still a newbie with C, so I made a lot of confusion.
This code works fine

```
int error(int a, int b, int c)
{ 
  
  if (( a < 0 ) || (a > 255)) {
  printf("Number is over 255 or under 0, exit \n");
  exit(1); }

  if ((a < 0)|| (a > 255)) {
  printf("Number is over 255 or under 0, exit \n");
  exit(1);
  }
  else if ((b < 0)|| (b > 255)) {
  printf("Number is over 255 or under 0, exit \n");
  exit(1);
  } 
  else if ((c < 0)|| (c > 255)) {
  printf("Number is over 255 or under 0, exit \n");
  exit(1);
  } 
  else {
  true;
 }
}
```

But is too long and I don't like it, I want to create an array which take the values of a b and c, and compare it with 255 or 0 (separately: for example a=256 failed, b=23 ok, c=33 ok), and if is over 255 or under 0, exit.
I have tried this code but I have failed

```
int array[] = {a, b, c};
  
        if( array[a] >= MAX_SIZE){
         printf("Number is over 255 or under 0, exit \n");
         exit(1);
     }
```

Comment: The statement `true;` doesn't really do anything. And if you declare a function to return a non-void value, then you must have an explicit `return` statement.

Comment: Yes I know, I have inserted it for "exit" from the loop, I already tried this code and work I only want to convert it to an array because is too long

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters it is not a godd design when the program exits from the function.

Using an array your function can look the following way

```
bool error(int a, int b, int c)
{ 
    int data[] = { a, b, c };
    size_t n = sizeof( data ) / sizeof( *data );

    size_t i = 0;

    while ( i < n && !( data[i] < 0 || data[i] > 255 ) ) i++;

    if ( i != n )
    {   
        printf("Number is over 255 or under 0, exit \n");
    }

    return i == n;
}
```

Though as the function is named `error` then it should return `true` when the numbers do not satisfy the condition that is it is better to rewrite the return statement like

```
return i != n;
```

Also pay attention to that the function should not output any message. It is the caller of the function based on the return value will decide whether to output a message. So I would define the function the following way

```
bool error(int a, int b, int c)
{ 
    int data[] = { a, b, c };
    size_t n = sizeof( data ) / sizeof( *data );

    size_t i = 0;

    while ( i < n && !( data[i] < 0 || data[i] > 255 ) ) i++;

    return i != n;
}
```

and in the caller you can write

```
if ( error( a, b, c ) )
{
    printf("Number is over 255 or under 0, exit \n");
}
```

If you want to use an array of values then the function can look the following way

```
bool error( const int data[], size_t n, int low, int high )
{ 
    size_t i = 0;

    while ( i < n && !( data[i] < low || data[i] > high ) ) i++;

    return i != n;
}
```

The values of `low` and `high` can be for example `1` and `255`.

Comment: Perfect, thanks

Comment: Error in line     size_t n = sizeof( data ) / sizeof( *data ), works with     size_t n = sizeof( data ) / sizeof( *data );

Comment: Also this line cause me problem `    while ( i < n && !( data[i] <= 0 || data[i] > 255 ) ) i++;` while `    while ( i < n && !( data[i] < 0 || data[i] > 255 ) ) i++;` works fine

Comment: @elbarna There was a typo: a missed semicolon.

Answer (score 2):

Simply iterate through the elements of the array with all the values:

```
#include <stdbool.h>

static inline bool is_in_range(int val, int start, int end) 
{
     return val >= start && val <= end;
} 

...
int array[] = {a, b, c};
  
for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof array / sizeof *array; ++i) {
    if(!is_in_range(array[i], 0, 255)) {
        printf("Number is over 255 or under 0, exit \n");
        exit(1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would keep the logic basically as-is, but try to combine it into a single condition:

```
void error(int a, int b, int c)
{
    if (a < 0 || b < 0 || c < 0 ||
        a > 255 || b > 255 || c > 255)
    {
        printf("Invalid input, one of the numbers is outside the range 0-255\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

Note that I have changed the return-type to `void`, because if the check fails then the program exits. If the function returns then the values are valid.

On a different note, the name `error` doesn't really describe what the function does. Perhaps something like `verify_values_range` would be better?

Comment: Thanks, is much short and better than mine, but you have to use a b c..a b c are only 3 vars and is ok, but my idea is another: is not possible for a lot of values an if-else statement using an array? So you have to write only once, for example, instead of use a b c d e f use a single array with values of a-f

Comment: @elbarna If you want an arbitrary number of arguments, then I suggest a vararg function instead, with the first argument being the number of values you pass. Then you check each value one by one in a loop.